# TypeError: 'str' is not callable (Flask form validation)

Tags: python, typeerror, flask-wtforms

I've found many topics here on SO that are related to this, however none of them helps resolve the problem I'm facing. I understand that in my code somewhere is a function expected but it gets string instead.

Relevant code:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(Form):
    photo = FileField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    country = SelectField('','Select Country', choices=countries)
    first_name = StringField('',[validators.Length(min=1,max=20), DataRequired()])
    middle_name = StringField('',[validators.Length(min=1,max=20), DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('',[validators.Length(min=1,max=20), DataRequired()])
    dob = DateField('',format='YYYY-MM-DD', validators=[DataRequired()])
    address = TextAreaField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = EmailField('', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    mobile_number = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('', validators=[DataRequired()])

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():  # here's where the error is coming from

    file_name = request.files.getlist('photo')
    if file_name[-4:] not in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
        flash('Invalid Image Type.')

    else:
        file_name = file_name.filename
        destination = '/'.join([TARGET, file_name])
        file_name.save(destination)

        country = form.country.data
        first_name = form.first_name.data
        middle_name = form.middle_name.data
        last_name = form.last_name.data
        dob = form.dob.data
        address = form.address.data
        email = form.email.data
        mobile_number = form.mobile_number.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))  # according to tutorial the string conversion here is correct.
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this error ? Have been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
    country = SelectField('','Select Country', choices=countries)
```

Should be

```
    country = SelectField('Select Country', choices=countries)
```

Label should be the first argument, the second argument is the validator. Your code is passing `'Select Country'` as the validator, which will obviously fail.

Comment: Well ... I fixed it and I got new error but at least it's something I know how to fix. Flask is great but doesn't do a good job at telling exactly where the error is. Thanks for reviewing my code @noteness